# Counting Consecutive Buy and Sell Trades in Pine Script v5

Tags: for-loop, pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm facing an issue with counting consecutive Buy and Sell trades in Pine Script v5. Currently, my code counts the trades separately for Buy (b) and Sell (s), but I would like to count them in consecutive blocks.

For example, if my trade sequence looks like: b, b, b, b, s, s, b, s, b, s, s, s, s, s, b

The counter should work as follows:

4 times Buy (b)
If a Sell trade (s) occurs after 4 consecutive Buy trades, the counter should reset and start counting from 0 again.
However, the last highest count value should be preserved.
If 6 consecutive Buy trades occur, the counter should be adjusted accordingly.

```
var int tradecountS = 0
var int tradecountB = 0

var int is_last_buy = 0
var int is_last_sell = 0

if lowerin and timeok
    strategy.order("Buy", strategy.long)
        

if upperin and timeok
    strategy.order("Sell", strategy.short)
    

for i = 0 to strategy.closedtrades -1
    tradeid = strategy.closedtrades.exit_id(i)

    if tradeid == "Sell"
        tradecountS := tradecountS + 1 
        tradecountB := 0
        is_last_sell := math.max(is_last_sell, tradecountS)

    if tradeid == "Buy"
        tradecountB := tradecountB + 1
        tradecountS := 0
        is_last_buy := math.max(is_last_buy, tradecountB)

var buyselltable = table.new(position = position.bottom_center, columns = 2, rows = 1, bgcolor = color.gray)
table.cell(table_id = buyselltable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "Buy trades: " + str.tostring(is_last_buy))
table.cell(table_id = buyselltable, column = 1, row = 0, text = "Sell trades: " + str.tostring(is_last_sell))
```